# Saving the content of a file in an elasticsearch index using springboot RESTAPI

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, elasticsearch, file-upload

So I am building a Spring Boot rest api that it takes a file ( Multipart file ) ( and it is a log file ) as an argument and saves its content in a unique  elasticsearch index ! Each line of the file will be in a document. so my plan was :
1- create the index.
2- read each line of the file
3- save this line in the index.

the version elasticsearch  that I am using is : 8.6

**the problem :**  I am dealing with big files ( their size can reach to 200mb) and when I tested my code, it took hours just for an average file ( size way too smaller than 100mb )

this is my code ( I used the buffer reader and elasticsearch java api client ) :

```
// Creating the index 
String indexName = "newIndex";

CreateIndexResponse createResponse =client.indices().create(
                new CreateIndexRequest.Builder()
                .index(indexName)
                .build()
                );
// read each line and save it 
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))){
            
            String line ="";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    LogFile log = new LogFile(); // the code is below this
                    log.setMessage(line);
                    IndexResponse resp = client.index(i -> i
                            .index(indexName)
                            .document(log));
                        } 
            }
}
```

```
// the code of the class LogFile 
@Document(indexName = "log-model")
@Data
public class LogFile {

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String message;

}
```

**What I am looking for :**  How can I improve my code ? is there a library or another tool like logstach or something that i can use to load theese type of files in a shorter time ! I ve been searching for more than one week and I didn't find anything helpful

Comment: have you tried bulk insert https://stackoverflow.com/a/51868683/175554 and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing-bulk.html